How to Force Hibernate dialect programmatically
When the service starts, if the SQL server is unreachable, I get the following error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided)

This error message is not very helpful for the support team. It seems that because Hibernate can't reach the SQL server, it fails to discover the dialect, masking the actual issue which is the server being unreachable.
I suspect that if I force Hibernate to use a specific dialect, it will bypass this initial error and directly reveal the underlying connection issue.
I am reading the configuration from a custom YAML structure. Here is my setup for the data source:
@Bean
DataSource dataSource(DataSourceProperties props) {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

    dataSource.setDriverClassName(props.getDriverClassName());
    dataSource.setUrl(props.getUrl());

    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(props.getUsername())) {
        dataSource.setUsername(props.getUsername());
    }
    if (!StringUtils.isBlank(props.getPassword())) {
        dataSource.setPassword(props.getPassword());
    }
    
    log.info("Connecting to {}, user {}", dataSource.getUrl(), props.getUsername());

    return dataSource;
}   

I can't find any DataSource property that sets the dialect. How can I force Hibernate to use a specific dialect to uncover the actual connection error?

If I started Database then I do not find this message, otherwise I find exactly this one in Spring boot 3.3.

Also when driver is misplaced in configuration.

Simple add to Config file:
System.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect")

With the dialect set the Spring will not try to connect at startup.

Use this properties (n the description of your error it tells you):
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

or this properties
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect

AND/OR
jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url

Configure in Code JAVA, persistence.xml, application.properties or application.yaml
for example in persistence.xml (JTA + JPA using JNDI no need configure user AND password in APP or properties)
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    ...
    <persistence-unit name="UNIT_NAME_ANY" transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>Unidad de persistencia</description>
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jndi/NameAny</jta-data-source>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            ...
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            ...
        </properties>
    ...
    </persistence-unit>
    ...
</persistence>

